# Django channels using secured WebSocket connection - WSS://

Tags: javascript, python, ssl, websocket, wss

When I tried to run the Django application using `sslserver` as shown below,

```
python manage.py runsslserver
```

**Errors:**

*Traceback:*

```
Validating models...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
November 08, 2019 - 11:17:26
Django version 2.0.7, using settings 'dashboard_channels.settings'
Starting development server at https://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using SSL certificate: \lib\site-packages\sslserver\certs\development.crt
Using SSL key: \lib\site-packages\sslserver\certs\development.key
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[08/Nov/2019 11:18:33] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1299
[08/Nov/2019 11:18:34] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1299
[08/Nov/2019 11:18:35] "GET /static/js/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 270575
Not Found: /ws/home
[08/Nov/2019 11:18:36] "GET /ws/home HTTP/1.1" 404 2134
```

*Browser Console:*

```
(index):31 WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/home' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
(index):41 error Event
(index):44 close CloseEvent
```

**Code:**

*Javascript:*

```
 var loc = window.location;
 var wsStart = 'ws://';
 if (loc.protocol == 'https:') {
     wsStart = 'wss://'
 }
 var endpoint = wsStart + loc.host + '/ws/home';

 var socket = new WebSocket(endpoint);
```

It's working fine with `python manage.py runserver` command, means for `http` it's working but not with `https`.

How to resolve this issue? (How to debug to sort out this issue?)

Is there any other way to deploy WebSockets on `https` portal?

Still facing this issue. Can anyone please help?

<sub>Anyhow this is for testing purposes, finally, I need to deploy it on Apache2.4 in the windows server machine. Where I have already set up for `https` but not for web sockets.</sub>

Comment: It says *Not Found: /ws/home*. Does it say the same for http?

Comment: No, it's working properly. There is no issue with `http`.

Comment: @shaikmoeed Please check if you configured CHANNEL_LAYERS in settings.py

Comment: @wowkin2 `CHANNEL_LAYERS` was configured and it's working totally fine with `http`. How to run on `https`?

Comment: @shaikmoeed have you tried to use Daphne for that? If not - really recommend to do that: https://github.com/django/daphne

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the answer, the `runserver` command correctly detects `asgi.py` file and run the Django channels application on WebSockets using daphne. Somehow `runsslserver` is not doing the same job, It's running the `wsgi.py` file instead of `asgi.py` file.

After reading different approaches, I get to know that we can handle `HTTPS` request using our normal development server (i.e., using `wsgi.py` file) and `wss` request by using `Daphne`(i.e., using `asgi.py` file).

Daphne was an officially designed server to handle django-channels(built on the top of the twisted module).

So, finally, we need to run two servers to handle `https` and `wss` separately.

```
# In command prompt 1 (For production, use Apache or Nginx to serve HTTP requests)
python manage.py runsslserver 0.0.0.0:8000

# In command prompt 2 (This works for production as well).
daphne -e ssl:8001:privateKey=cert\\private.pem:certKey=cert\\public.pem real_time_table.asgi:application
```

> We should use the same SSL certificates used by `runsslserver` for
>   testing.

Finally, in JavaScript:

```
var loc = window.location;
var wsStart = 'ws://';
if (loc.protocol == 'https:') {
     wsStart = 'wss://'
}
// var endpoint = wsStart + 'your_ip_address:port_given_to_daphne_server' + '/ws/home';
// For above command, it look like this
var endpoint = wsStart + 'xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8001' + '/ws/home';
// Note the websocket port is 8001
var socket = new WebSocket(endpoint);
```

I hope, this will save someone's time.

Comment: Does command from prompt 2 use the certification keys generated by the first command `runsslserver`?

Comment: Yes, we need to use same certificates for both servers i.e., `wsgi` and `asgi` servers.